# draw parabola with vertex coordinates python

Tags: python, python-2.7, plot, coordinates, vertex

I want to draw a parabola with python 2.7 knowing the coordinates of the vertex.

At the moment I have implemented this. The issue is that the vertex is not on the parabola, in fact it plots a parabola and a separate point. Could anybody point out the error? Thank you.

```
def parabola(return_hist1,V):
    #solve the equations and plot the parabola

    # V[0] is the x-coordinate and V[1] is the y-coordinate

    A=np.array([[2*V[0]],[4*V[1]]])
    B=np.array([[1],[-1]])
    sol=A*B

    Y=range(int(V[1]),50)
    X=[]
    for e in Y:
        X.append(sol[0]*e**2 + sol[1]*e)

    plt.plot(X,Y)
    plt.plot(V[0],V[1],'ro')
    plt.show()
    return
```

Comment: You want to draw a parabola only using one point? I'm afraid I don't understand - you need three points to back-track the parabola because you have three unknowns to calculate

Comment: Thank you, Manuel, for your reply. I know that v[0]= -b/(2*a) and v[1] = -b**2/4a (as I set c = 0). the directrix is equal to y = V[1]. Aren't these pieces of information enough to plot it?

Comment: Have you tried `Y=range(int(V[1])-1,50)` ?

Answer (score -1):

Guessing this is what you are looking for:

```
# create parabola
X = np.linspace(-20,20,1000) # range of parabola: -20,20 in 1000 steps
Y = X**2 # calculate square of each X value to create a parabola at 0/0
# move lowest point of parabola to V
X += V[0]
Y += V[1]
# plot ...
```

Swap X/Y to rotate by 90 degrees.

A parabola usually has the equation `y = a(x-X)**2+Y` with `V=(X,Y)`. By only knowing `V` you won't be able to determin the stretch-factor `a`. Nor if the user of `parabola` wants it to be vertically or horizontally.